# Meaning of "until"

Tags: meaning

I read the sentence below. What is the purpose of using "until" in the sentence? I can understand the whole sentence without "until."

> But the more carefully nature has been studied, the more widely has order been found to prevail, while what seemed disorder has proved to be nothing but complexity, ***until***, at present, no one is so foolish as to believe that anything happens by chance or that there are any real accidents, in the sense of events which have no cause.

Comment: It means that the writer doesn't know how to write coherently.

Comment: The quotation is inaccurate, leaving out the beginning of the sentence and relevant punctuation. Thus, it’s just garbled. Unfair to us and the author.

Comment: The more we study nature, the more we find that order prevails, up until now, that we see that nothing happens by chance at all. All events have a cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without *until*, it would fall apart into two separate sentences.

The function of *until* is to tie these two together. The first half describes a long-drawn-out continuing process *the more carefully nature has been studied, the more widely has order been found to prevail*, and the second half describes the stage which that process has now reached.

There is no *explicit* mention of time in the first half, but our knowledge of the real world allows us to infer that the writer is talking about a long process. The writer is presenting "now" as an end-point, or at least an end-point so far.